# Have numbers of this form forced small factors?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, reference-request, fibonacci-numbers, prime-factorization

Let $F_n$ be the $n$ th Fibonacci-number and define $$f(n):=F_{n^2}-F_n+1$$

For most integers $n>1$ , $f(n)$ has a small prime factor :

```
2  3
3  3
4  5
5  3
6  5
7  11
8  227
9  3727
10  3
11  3
12  5
13  3
14  2099
15  307
16  7445729
17  11
18  3
19  3
20  197921
21  3
22  137
23  11
24  5
25  103681
26  3
27  3
28  81209593
29  3
30  547
31  17
32  5
33  11
34  3
35  3
36  701
37  3
38  5
39  647
40  353
41  17
42  3
43  3
44  5
45  3
46  5
47  11
48  40759
49  79
50  3
51  3
52  5
53  3
54  ?
```

The smallest prime factor of $f(54)$ has probably more than $25$ digits.

> Can it be proven that $f(n)$ is composite for every integer $n>2$ by finding a forced factor ?
> $f(n)$ is prime for $n=2$ and no other integer $n\le 700$ ?

Update :

- $P33 = 107407032520007517281843885218879$  divides $F(54)$
- $P28 = 1731761941976002747853061853$ divides $F(94)$

[factordb](http://factordb.com/index.php?query=I%28n%5E2%29-I%28n%29%2B1&use=n&n=0&VP=on&VC=on&EV=on&OD=on&PR=on&PRP=on&U=on&C=on&perpage=100&format=1&sent=Show)

Any ideas ?

Comment: I don't understand what content there is to the phrase "forced factor" (or even "small factor") in these examples. It seems you're simply claiming that these numbers are composite. They grow so fast that it's reasonable, just on probabilistic groups, to suspect that there are few or no prime values later in the sequence.

Comment: I'd be curious to hear about the motivation for this problem.

Comment: Is the core question here just "Is $f(n)$ composite for all $n>2$?"?

Comment: @EricSnyder Yes , as indicated in the question